# Div not floating to top

Tags: html, css

I've created a basic HTML page layout with 3 divs. The third div (sidebar) meant float to top right but it floats on the right but under the 1st div.

Does anyone know where I am going wrong?

So the green div (sidebar) should float to top right when the window is maximised, and if the window is resized, it should float on the right under the div 1 and alongside div 2

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Untitled 1</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles1.css" type="text/css" />

<style type="text/css">

.page {
 width:90%;
}

.div1 {
 width: 750px;
 background-color: gray;
 float:left;
}

.div2 {
 width: 60%;
 background-color: blue;
 float:left;
}

.sidebar {
 width: 30%;
 background-color: green;
 float: right;
}

</style>

</head>



<body>

<div class="page">
 <div class="div1">
 <p>div1</p>
 </div>
 
 <div class="div2">
 <p>div2</p>
 </div>
 
 <div class="sidebar">
 <p>sidebar</p>
 </div>

</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you have any experience with flex? https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ or you could use the bootstrap grid. Give me a minute and ill fix it.

Comment: Never used flex but this looks very interesting

Comment: `.sidebar` is a child of `.page` which has a constrained width. `.sidebar` is all the way to the right edge of the `.page`. Give `.page` a non-zero height and a background color to see it.

Answer (score 0):

consider this code snippet, I switched the '.div2 'and '.sidebar' positions

```css
.page {
 width:90%;
}

.div1 {
 width: 750px;
 background-color: gray;
 float:left;
}

.div2 {
 width: 60%;
 background-color: blue;
 float:left;
}

.sidebar {
 width: 30%;
 background-color: green;
 float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
 <div class="div1">
 <p>div1</p>
 </div>
 
 <div class="sidebar">
 <p>sidebar</p>
 </div>
  
 <div class="div2">
 <p>div2</p>   
 </div>
 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS Grid Layout system. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Untitled 1</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles1.css" type="text/css" />

<style type="text/css">

.page {
 width:90%;
  float:left;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
  'header header sidebar'
  'main main sidebar';
}

.div1 {
  grid-area: header;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
  float:left;
  padding:7px;
  color:#fff;
}

.div2 {
  grid-area: main;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  float:left;
  padding:7px;
  color:#fff;
}

.sidebar {
  grid-area: sidebar;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  float: left;
  padding:7px;
  color:#fff;
}

</style>

</head>



<body>

<div class="page">
 <div class="div1">
 <p>div1</p>
 </div>
 
 <div class="div2">
 <p>div2</p>
 </div>
 
 <div class="sidebar">
 <p>sidebar</p>
 </div>

</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why doing it this way works (switching div2 and sidebar positions), but not the way I did it? But doing it that way won't make the sidebar float to the bottom when window is resized. So when window is resized, div1 is at the top, then div2 in middle and finally sidebar at the bottom